# Theme that includes a "core" plugin but the files in theme and child folder ignored

Tags: plugins, child-theme

I have purchased to themes from Qode which my client has chosen.

Both themes have a "core" plugin which is used for specific areas, like "events", breadcrumbs and portfolios" etc.

Firstly, annoyingly the theme does not support breadcrumbs for custom post types so I needed to change the file that displays these, which I have done via the core plugin fine, but I am aware that during an update this will probably get overridden.

I have tried to save the file I edited within both the main theme and child theme in the same hierarchy as the plugin but still the plugin files are the ones used - not the ones in either the theme or child folders.

How do I get the site to use the files for the plugin that are now stored within the theme or even better, the child theme?

Never had this issue before so really stumped - any help appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not going to work.

Only files you find in the parent theme can be overridden in a child theme, and even at that it's only the actual WordPress specific files that will be overridden.

The only real way you would be able to do this is if the theme developer integrated a function to check for those files, or used filters for it.

My experience with Qode though this is not possible at all, and you will not find any easy way of doing this.